# Azure CLI storage Batch Copy not working on mac Seira

Tags: macos, azure, azure-cli, azcopy, azure-cli2

I have an AzCopy command on windows that copies all blobs from a storage account to a local network drive and tests to make sure the file doesn't already exist before copying.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/photos /Dest:C:\folder /SourceKey:xxxxxkeyxxxxxxx /S /XO /XN
```

This command is working perfectly. However i need to set up this same process on a mac.  I have installed the Azure CLI tools and have created the following batch copy command.  I have dryrun while i was testing

```
az storage blob copy start-batch \
--destination-container "/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/folder" \
—-source-account-key xxxxkeyxxxx \
—-source-account-name storage \
—-source-uri https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/photos \
--dryrun
```

But i get the following error message

```
az: error: unrecognized arguments: Backup Plus Drive/New folder 
—-source-account-key xxxxkeyxxxx 
—-source-account-name storage 
—-source-uri https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/photos
```

I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli) that you can use AzCopy through the Azure CLI.  But when i tried it it said command not found.

I'm a complete Mac newbie and not sure what i am doing wrong. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

This process also needs to be set up as a batch process for a non-tech person to be able to run.  I haven't looked into this yet as wanted to get the copy working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your script.

Firstly, `Seagate Backup Plus Drive` There are three spaces. When you use Azure CLi, you should use `%20` to replace it. For example:

```
/Volumes/Seagate%20Backup%20Plus%20Drive
```

You could check it on Azure Portal.

[image]

Secondly, `—-source-account-key xxxxkeyxxxx` this is wrong. The correct format is `--source-account-key xxxxkeyxxxx`. If you look carefully, `—-` and `--` are different.

You also need replace `—-source-account-name storage`  and `—-source-uri https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/photos` they are same mistake.

Comment: Thanks heaps @shengbao.  Its running now but its saying "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server" for the --destination-container.  The destination container is a local harddrive and not another azure storage account.  How can i get this script to copy down to a local drive? Or should i be doing this another way?

Comment: @Andrew This command is used for copy file between storage account.  If you want to upload file, you should use `az storage blob upload`.

Comment: No i wish to download from Azure

Comment: You could use `az storage blob download`, see this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161670/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-andrew).

Comment: Apologise for the delay in getting back to you.....Thanks heaps for your help.....I have the following code working.......  az storage blob download-batch \
 --destination //localdrive/photos \
 --source https://storageName.blob.core.windows.net/photos \
 --account-key xxxxkeyxxxx \
 --account-name storageName \